# Black lines on a rendered object

Tags: rendering

I rendered a gumdrop while following Blender guru's tutorial. but there is strange black lines around the contour of the object.

I changed some of settings for shadow but that did not solve the problem. Please let me know if you have any clue.
Here is my model (https://pasteall.org/blend/8f7a259788c24d1b8a13579d87ab65b6).

[image: gumdrop]